# Probability - Coin Tossing

Tags: probability

As I'm practicing the Probability, I found this question, and I'm interested in knowing how to solve it! Would you please explain it!

It's not my homework. it's an old one from [here](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/class/10701-F09/hws/hw1/hw1.pdf). So I just want to practice!

I am just reiterating the question here.

> We have two coins, one fair and one biased. The probability of
>   bringing heads with the biased coin is 1/20.We close our eyes and
>   choose one of the two coins and we toss it twice. Each coin has
>   probability 1/2 of being chosen. Compute the probability of:
>
> 1. [1 pts] bringing heads in the ﬁrst toss.
> 2. [3 pts] having chosen the fair coin given that both tosses were heads.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [maths.se]

Answer (score 2):

> 1. [1 pts] bringing heads in the ﬁrst toss

(probability of choosing the biased coin and probability of getting head ) or ( probability of choosing the unbiased coin and probability getting a head) = 1/2 * 1/20 + 1/2 * 1/2 = 11/40

> 1. [3 pts] having chosen the fair coin given that both tosses were heads.

p(A/B) = p(B/A) * P(A)/p(B)

p(A/B) = probability of having chosen fair coin when both tosses were heads

p(B/A) = probability of getting head when we have chooses the fair coin = 1/2 * 1/2

p(A ) = probability of choosing a fair coin = 1/2

p(B) = probability of getting getting head in both tosses = 1/2*1/2*1/2 + 1/2*1/20*1/20

So you can calculate the total.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some explanation in my way.

```
1)   
Lets show the coins as F=Fair, B=Biased
Since, the probability of selecting the each coin is 1/2.
P(F) = 0.5, P(B) = 0.5
And the question now is bringing the heads in the first toss.
If we toss the Fair coin, the probability of getting head will be:
0.5
If we toss the Biased coin, the probability of getting head will be:
1/20 = 0.05

Therefore, the probability of getting head in first attempt is:
(0.5*0.5 + 0.5*0.05)/2 = (0.25+0.025)/2


2)  
The probability of choosing pair coin = 0.5
Given condition, two tosses are resulted with head.
P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A) / P(B)
The probability of getting two heads consecutively is:
let say P(B),
P(B) = 1/4; //since we can have the result as (HH,HT,TH,TT) .. so HH --> 1/4
P(B|F) = Getting HEAD twice if we choose Fair coin
P(B|F) = 0.25
P(F) = 0.5

therefore,
P(F|B) = 0.25*0.5/0.25 = 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Biased coin produces a pair of heads 1/400 of the time. Fair coin produces a pair of heads 1/4 of the time. So for every pair of heads from the biased coin there will be 100 pairs of heads from the fair coin. Answer 100/101.

Comment: Question is off-topic.